# prevention from duplicated input in a form

Tags: php, validation

i have a problem, this is my code and when I add a new input with same name(nazov) it gets in database so it is duplicated. help please

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    //get the name and comment entered by user
    $nazov = $_POST['nazov'];


    //connect to the database
    $prip=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx") or die('Error connecting to MySQL server');

    //insert results from the form input
    $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO trieda (nazov) VALUES('$_POST[nazov]')";

    $result = mysqli_query($prip, $sql) or die(mysqli_errno($prip) == 1062 ? "Trieda už existuje" : 'Chyba načítavania databázy.');

    mysqli_close($prip);
}
```

Comment: Check if you have that value in your db before the insert.

Comment: You are using `mysqli_*` and not using prepared statements. In your database that column should be a unique index, then handle your errors (for duplicate values) properly, or you can check for duplicates using php before insertion.

Comment: you can fetch the data from table and then check  or you can make the `name` column as unique in your database.

Comment: okay, I set it to be unique and edited my code a little but what it does now is that doesnt duplicate the data in DB, it is working great but the text it shows is not correct. It shows every time that the record was added. 

     if (mysqli_query($prip, $sql)) {
      echo $add;
     }else{
      echo $not_add;
      }
     
    
    mysqli_close($prip);
    }

Answer (score 0):

you can set the filed you want to be unique in your MYSQL database. So if you try to add the same value you just get error.

You can also do a select first and check if data exists in database before you insert it.

You can do the lazy solution and use **REPLACE** instead of INSERT. REPLACE updates it, if it exists and insert if not.

Comment: Alireza, thanks for the REPLACE solution bout I would rather use another one, I dont want to replace it for future reference...